# Understanding lgbm histogram building

Tags: xgboost, boosting, lightgbm, gradient-boosting-decision-trees, histogram

```
Input: I: training data, d: max depth
Input: m: feature dimension
nodeSet ← {0} . tree nodes in current level
rowSet ← {{0, 1, 2, ...}} . data indices in tree nodes
for i = 1 to d do
    for node in nodeSet do
        usedRows ← rowSet[node]
        for k = 1 to m do
            H ← new Histogram()
            . Build histogram
            for j in usedRows do
                bin ← I.f[k][j].bin
                H[bin].y ← H[bin].y + I.y[j]
                H[bin].n ← H[bin].n + 1
        Find the best split on histogram H.
        ...
    Update rowSet and nodeSet according to the best
    split points.
```

Can you please help me understand the histogram building approach in the algorithm above. This is straight from the [lgbm manuscript](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2017/file/6449f44a102fde848669bdd9eb6b76fa-Paper.pdf)

What I do not understand:

1. What is the bin <- I.f[k][j].bin line doing? It seems that before even starting the algorithm, lgbm is splitting the overall data in bins (global, at the root itself, without any splits having happened so far). Then the algorithm is retreiving that bin every time it is creating the bins for a node. If it right then what is the point of this?

Basically, the problem here is to find the histogram for the datapoints in a node. I cannot understand how lgbm is achieving that. lgbm later on uses this histogram to find the appropriate splits

Comment: cross-posted at CV.SE: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/627572/232706

Comment: I think the lines `H ← new Histogram` and `. Build histogram` lines are supposed to indicate creating the histogram for this node, and the subsequent lines just show how to populate the relevant statistics?